# How to make get if the combobox contains more than one item with same text or not in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, combobox

I want get a message box.

If items in the combo box contain more than one item with the same text.

In Visual Studio 2017 in VB.NET.

Comment: Do you just need to know if there are any duplicates or do you need a list of all the duplicate items?

Comment: I want to make  (" for next ") for combobox items and if the current item text there is another item with the same text = do nothing  if not do action

Comment: Please show us what you have and we could help you from there on

Comment: sorry I mean that I have combo box with 20 values and contain a values that has the same text maybe 2 or 3 , so I want to add these 20 to list box but without duplication . eg: combo box contain (jack , jonny , peter , jonny , sam , peter , david , jain, liam ) I want to add these values in listbox like ( jack , jonny ,peter ,sam ,david ,jain ,liam ) .

Comment: Please move the relevant information from comments to the question by [editing (changing)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52895025/edit) it.

Comment: It is tagged with Visual Studio 2015, but the body says  Visual Studio 2017. Which one?

Answer (score 0):

It’s a pretty straightforward thing to do. It helps if you break a process down into the individual things you want to do. Like this

- Iterate through each item in the combobox.
- 
- For each iteration, get the item's location and compare the item to each item after it to see if they match.
- If there is a match, end the search and return a true result

Then you need to write code that does what you want - this should work ok based on the assumption that the items in the combobox are strings.

```
Public Function HasDuplicate(cboBox As ComboBox) As Boolean
    For Each item As Object In cboBox.Items
        For i As Integer = cboBox.Items.IndexOf(item) + 1 To cboBox.Items.Count - 2
            If cboBox.Items.Item(i).ToString = item.ToString Then
                HasDuplicate = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return HasDuplicate
End Function
```

The first loop gets the item and the inner loop iterates through the combobox from the next item and compares the items to see if there is a match.

If there is a match, the result is set to True and the loop is stopped.

Finally the result it returned.

Comment: sorry I mean that I have combo box with 20 values and contain a values that has the same text maybe 2 or 3  , so I want to add these 20 to list box but without duplication . eg: combo box contain (jack , jonny , peter , jonny , sam , peter , david , jain, liam ) I want to add these values in listbox like ( jack , jonny ,peter ,sam ,david ,jain ,liam ) .

Comment: Fair enough - the way you should do it then is to iterate through your combobox check if the current item in the iteration is already in the listbox. if it isnt, then add it to the listbox. I mean this most politely - as I said at the beginning of the answer, this isnt a tutorial site, and to be honest, the best way to learn is to research things. Such as figuring out what you want to do and how to use the language to accomplish it. I know it seems like a mammoth task, but learning a programming language is exactly that :-)